# discrete distribution in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I need discrete distribution in tensorflow。

- But when I search the documentation from tensorflow，I can only find
  normal distribution and so on.
- In theano, I often use
  theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams.RandomStreams.choice method to
  generate discrete distribution。
- And also, I Google this problem。And I found 
  tf.contrib.distributions.DiscreteDistribution。 But this is an
  abstract class。I cannot use it directly。

So，here is question。How to implement discrete distribution in tensorflow。
Thanks for your help。

Comment: Would this help? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/contrib.distributions.md

Comment: Thanks for your help。But as I said ，tf.contrib.distributions.DiscreteDistribution is an abstract class，I cannot use it directly。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own discrete 0-1 variable by doing `tf.random.uniform() > 0.5`, this can be easily extended to other discrete distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these fit the bill?

```
 ds = tf.contrib.distributions
 ds.Bernoulli
 ds.Binomial
 ds.Categorical
 ds.Deterministic
 ds.OneHotCategorical
```